# IOS: #import <AddressBook/AddressBookUI.h> file not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have included both frameworks and import header files. But xCode throws an error because of the missing AddressBookUI.h file.

```
#import "PersonViewController.h"

#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface PersonViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AddressBookUI.h is in the AddressBookUI framework, not the AddressBook framework.

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your project explorer, select your project, then go to target>build phases>link binary with libraries and then add the library to your project, after that the import will work.